# Detectar Caps Lock C#

Tags: c#, .net

Fiz uma aplicação para detectar o estado do caps lock em C#, mas encontrei um problema, quando a aplicação perde o foco os eventos não podem mais ser disparados fazendo com que as notificações não sejam mais exibidas pela aplicação. Eu dei uma breve olhada na internet e vi que utilizando DLL's do windows é possível fazer isso. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: A resposta fornecida respondeu o que você queria? Você pode aceitá-la com correta. Senão souber como, veja em [about]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Usando [Console.CapsLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.capslock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 Console.WriteLine( "Caps Lock " + ( Console.CapsLock ? "Ligado" : "Desligado" ) );
```

Para checar o estado depois de voltar à aplicação, seria o caso de fazer um polling.

### Usando DLL:

Acrescente ao código:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Eis a detecção propriamente dita:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
   ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]

public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode); 

// CapsLock = 0x14, NumLock = 0x90 e ScrollLock = 0x91
bool CapsLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;

Console.WriteLine( "Caps Lock " + ( CapsLock ? "Ligado" : "Desligado" ) );
```

Comment: Não valeria a pena colocar um link para a listagem dos outros virtual-key codes existentes? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Os específicos para teclas de estado (que independem de estar pressionadas), eu coloquei no comment. As outras normalmente você usaria o c# mesmo, não precisaria da DLL. Em todo o caso, o link do seu comment é bom para acrescentar esta informação extra, caso alguém se interesse.